# Regex: Split on underscore, sometimes

Tags: regex

I have a string that can read either this format:

```
Static_1264_1264_11232013_1234
```

or this format:

```
Static_1264__11232013_1234
```

Note the second example has only one instance of '1264' and where the second one should be there are still pre and post-underscores. When I was guaranteed a value there I used this regex to split the string into variables I passed elsewhere:

```
([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^/]+)
```

But that doesn't see a match when the second number is missing. I tried adding the non-greedy value to the second piece, like so:

```
([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+?)_([^_]+)_([^/]+)
```

But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

`+` means "match the previous element one or more times".  If you want something to be optional, use a `*` instead which means "match the previous element zero or more times":

```
([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]*)_([^_]+)_([^/]+)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use

```
var str = 'Static_1264__1264_11232013_1234';
str.match(/([^_]+)/g);
```

Output:

```
["Static", "1264", "1264", "11232013", "1234"]
```